# ISO 3166-1 to woeid

Tags: iso, yahoo-maps, iso-3166

Where do I find a list of all countries woeid from their ISO 3166-1 alpha2 or alpha3 codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aral Balkan](http://twitter.com/aral) has something that you might enjoy

> http://openCountryCodes.appspot.com/

it includes the ISO *3166-1-alpha-2* list in **HTML**, **Python**, **JavaScript**, **ActionScript**, **Flex**, **JSON** and **XML**

with this, just hook up to **[Yahoo API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placemaker/)** and do your magic

Comment: Thank you, event though I allready had the ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 and 3 values. Your Yahoo API link opened a whole new world to me :o)

Comment: The URL in this answer works but none of the actual data retrieval URLs are currently working as of March 1 2012...

Comment: @hippietrail as said, the link is not mine, fell free to send an email to Aral -> twitter: https://twitter.com/#!/aral

Comment: Since the original link is broken, [here](https://github.com/stefangabos/world_countries) is an up to date such list

Answer (score 0):

See the GeoPlanet user guide: http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/
and http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/api-reference.html#api-countries

You can get a list of countries using an URL like: 
http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/countries?appid=[yourappidhere]